# drop down dependent in codeigniter active record

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am having a hard time figuring out how to make a make a drop down dependency(payment terms base on selected class name), when you select the name in the class table you the payment terms base on the sql table (see last table) base selection base on the classes level. I think there is something wrong with my javascript and CI model. I am very new in this codeigniter activerecord, Please help me with my concern and Thank you very much in advance

CLASS TABLE

```
  classes
  |-------|------------------|
  |  id   |       Name       |
  |-------|------------------|
  |   1   |   Grade 1        |
  |-------|------------------|
  |   2   |   Grade 2        |
  |-------|------------------|
```

PAYMENT TERMS TABLE

```
  payment_terms
  |--------|------------------------------------|
  |   id   |       payment_terms                |
  |--------|------------------------------------|
  |   1    |   Grade 1    Full Payment          |
  |--------|------------------------------------|
  |   2    |   Grade 1    Quarterly Payment     |
  |--------|------------------------------------|
  |   3    |   Grade 2    Full Payment          |
  |--------|------------------------------------|
  |   4    |   Grade 2    Quarterly Payment     |
  |--------|------------------------------------|
```

ACADEMIC YEAR TABLE

```
  academic_year 
  |--------|------------------------------------|
  |   id   |       academic_year                |
  |--------|------------------------------------|
  |   1    |         2018-2019                  |
  |--------|------------------------------------|
```

ACADEMIC YEAR AND PAYMENT TERMS TABLE

```
  academic_year_payment_terms
  |--------|------------------|------------------|
  |   id   | academic_year_id | Payment_term_id  |
  |--------|------------------|------------------|
  |   1    | 1                | 1                |
  |--------|------------------|------------------|
  |   2    | 1                | 2                |
  |--------|------------------|------------------|
  |   3    | 1                | 3                |
  |--------|------------------|------------------|
  |   4    | 1                | 4                |
  |--------|------------------|------------------|
```

ACADEMIC YEAR PAYMENT TERMS AND CLASS TABLE

```
  academic_year_payment_terms_class
  |--------|-----------------------------|------------------|
  |   id   | academic_year_payment_terms | class_id         |
  |--------|-----------------------------|------------------|
  |   1    | 1                           | 1                |
  |--------|-----------------------------|------------------|
  |   2    | 2                           | 1                |
  |--------|-----------------------------|------------------|
  |   3    | 3                           | 2                |
  |--------|-----------------------------|------------------|
  |   4    | 4                           | 2                |
  |--------|-----------------------------|------------------|
```

My Codeigniter View

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select  id="class_id" name="class_id" class="form-control" >
     <option value=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('select'); ?></option>
         <?php
            foreach ($classlist as $class) { ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $class['id'] ?>"<?php
               if (set_value('class_id') == $class['id']){
                    echo "selected =selected";
               }
               ?>><?php echo $class['class'] ?></option>
            <?php
               $count++;
            }
            ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="academic_year_payment_terms_id" name="academic_year_payment_terms_id">
  </select>
</div>
```

My JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAcademicPaymentTermsByClass(class_id, academic_year_payment_terms_id {
    if (class_id != "" && academic_year_payment_terms_id != "") {
        $('#academic_year_payment_terms_id').html("");
        var base_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>';
        var div_data = '<option value=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('select'); ?></option>';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: base_url + "enrollment/fetchPaymentTermsByClass",
            data: {'class_id': class_id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, obj)
                {
                    var sel = "";
                    if (academic_year_payment_terms_id == obj.academic_year_payment_terms_id) {
                        sel = "selected";
                    }

                    div_data += "<option value=" + obj.academic_year_payment_terms_id+ " " + sel + ">" + obj.payment_terms + "</option>";
                });
                $('#academic_year_payment_terms_id').append(div_data);
            }
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
    var academic_year_payment_terms_id = '<?php echo set_value('academic_year_payment_terms_id') ?>';
    getAcademicPaymentTermsByClass(class_id, academic_year_payment_terms_id);

    $(document).on('change', '#class_id', function (e) {
        $('#academic_year_payment_terms_id').html("");
        var class_id = $(this).val();
        var base_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>';
        var div_data = '<option value=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('select'); ?></option>';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: base_url + "enrollment/fetchPaymentTermsByClass",
            data: {'class_id': class_id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, obj)
                {

                    div_data += "<option value=" + obj.academic_year_payment_terms_id' + ">" + obj.payment_terms' + "</option>";
                });
                $('#academic_year_payment_terms_id').append(div_data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My Enrollment Controller

```
   function fetchPaymentTermsByClass() {
    $class_id = $this->input->get('class_id');
    $data = $this->Enrollment_model->getPaymentTermsByClass($class_id);
    echo json_encode($data);
   }
```

My Enrollment model

```
   public function getPaymentTermsByClass($classid){
    $this->db->select('academic_year_payment_terms_class.id, academic_year_payment_terms_class.academic_year_payment_terms_id, academic_year_payment_terms.payment_terms');
    $this->db->from('academic_year_payment_terms_class');
    $this->db->join('academic_year_payment_terms', 'academic_year_payment_terms.id = academic_year_payment_terms_class.academic_year_payment_terms_id');
    $this->db->where('academic_year_payment_terms_class.class_id', $classid);
    $this->db->order_by('academic_year_payment_terms_class.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: when are you calling this function getAcademicPaymentTermsByClass(); instead of javascipt use jquery and same function for onchange event for class_id that should work

Comment: How about my CI model?

Comment: ci model function is called in controller so

Comment: i mean the code inside the model i dont know if i made it correctly becouse I call on all the tables which is in the top of my post... the javascript fucntion well in a many to many relationship but in this case i call on a many to many table and one of the row of the junction table was connected in a one to many table.

Comment: run application after making changes. if you get error you can debug

Comment: there no error appeared it is just  the 2nd dropdown is empty after i select from the first dropdown.